# Can't find '_sqlite3' module when import it using python which installed by pyenv

Tags: python, macos, sqlite, pip, homebrew

Installed python 3.7.0 by `pyenv` on macOS.

`sqlite3` has been installed:

```
which sqlite3
/usr/bin/sqlite3
```

Also tried to install `pysqlite3` by pip:

```
pip install pysqlite3
```

But can't find module when import `sqlite3`:

```
In [1]: import sqlite3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5239c6be4108> in <module>
----> 1 import sqlite3

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/__init__.py in <module>
     21 # 3. This notice may not be removed or altered from any source distribution.
     22
---> 23 from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py in <module>
     25 import collections.abc
     26
---> 27 from _sqlite3 import *
     28
     29 paramstyle = "qmark"

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

Is it necessary to install a develop library for sqlite3 on macOS by brew?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This way works:

```
CFLAGS="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" pyenv install 3.7.0
```

Ref:

> https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/108#issuecomment-359161050

Comment: what if I'm not on mac and dont have xcrun

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment. ensure sqlite related packages are installed